# problem reading .txt file in C# starting from (after immediate empty whole line) to (the next empty whole line)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, random, filereader

I am trying to randomly read a huge .txt file. It has tons of paragraphs separated by a full line of empty space prior and post each paragraph. I would like each time I randomly read that it pulls up a full intact paragraph without any characters or words missing for the sake of context. I appreciated the help in advance.

I added a for loop just to test it out and see if I can at some point include a way to recognize consecutively running empty space. That would only work post already selected the starting point obviously if applied.

```
public static string GetRandomLine(string filename)
{        
    var lines = File.ReadAllLines(filename);
    var lineNumber = _rand.Next(0, lines.Length);
    string reply = lines[lineNumber];


    return reply ;
}
```

Comment: You're not really randomly reading the text file. You're reading the whole text file each time this method is called and randomly selecting part of it. Try reading the file once and producing an index of paragraph start+length. Then randomly select from the index.

Comment: I want it to first select a random line. That random will be empty or contain characters. If it's empty, I want the output (reply) to be every character post the empty line all the way to the next empty line where it should cut out and return that result as a string. If it randomly selects a line in the middle of the paragraph, I want it to inch the position back until the beginning of the paragraph which will be recognized by a full empty line prior the paragraph. The last character of the string reply should be the last character of the paragraph prior the next whole empty line.

Comment: The index can help here, too... choose a random point and then search the index for the last paragraph start prior to that point.

Comment: Your long comment here outlines a solution very nicely, what sort of problems do you have implementing that solution?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen I'm new to stack-overflow and I made lots of edits to the code a few times. I removed some of the mistakes that were in the code. However you're right. If you could hopefully provide a code snippet of what I defined implemented within the example code that'd be great.

Comment: Characterizing the problem size as "huge" with "tons" of paras is vague, which makes it hard to help you. You might consider a hundred thousand lines "huge" and I might consider a million "pretty small" depending on what we were used to. Can you put some *numbers* on the size of the problem?  The techniques you'd use to solve this problem if there are millions of paras are different than those you'd use if there are thousands.

Comment: @EricLippert I definitely understand your concern. Stackoverflow rookie mistake. The .txt is 4332554 characters long. Thanks to the community I was able to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
        public static string[] GetRandomParagraph(string filePath)
        {
            if (File.Exists(filePath))
            {
                string text = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
                string[] paragraphs = text.Split(new string[] { "\n\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
                return paragraphs[new Random().Next(0, paragraphs.Length)].Split('\n');

            }
            else
                throw new FileNotFoundException("The file was not found", filePath);
        }
```

I really hope that is that what you are looking for.

Comment: Awesome! I made some changes to to your code for the purpose of my small project.Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To get intact paragraphs

```
public static string GetRandomParagraph(string fileName)
{
    /* 
       Rather than reading all the lines, read all the text
       this gives you the ability to split by paragraph
    */
    var allText = File.ReadAllText(fileName);
    // Use as separator for paragraphs
    var paragraphSeparator = $"{Environment.NewLine}{Environment.NewLine}";
    // Treat large white spaces after a new line as separate paragraphs 
    allText = Regex.Replace(allText, @"(\n\s{3,})", paragraphSeparator);
    // Split the text into paragraphs
    var paragraphs = allText.Split(paragraphSeparator);
    // Get a random index between 0 and the amount of paragraphs
    var randomParagraph = new Random().Next(0, paragraphs.Length);

    return paragraphs[randomParagraph];
}
```

Comment: This would fail in case some paragraphs are subsets of other paragraphs, for exemple if you have "hello dear" and "hello dear how are you today" and you want to find the first it may match the second if it comes first in the lines due to contains. Also no reason to split on \r\n instead of Environment.NewLine, would break if the file uses \n

Comment: @RonanThibaudau Thanks, I edited the answer to mitigate those issues

Answer (score 0):

```
// This builds a list of Paragraph first
public static List<string> GetParagraphs(string filename)
{        
    var paragraphs = new List<string>();
    var lines = File.ReadAllLines(filename);
    bool newParagraph = true;
    string CurrentParagraph = string.Empty;
    // Build the list of paragraphs by adding to the currentParagraph until empty lines and then starting a new one
    foreach(var line in lines)
    {
        if(newParagraph)
        {
            CurrentParagraph = line;
            newParagraph = false;
        }
        else
        {
            if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))// we're starting a new paragraph, add it to the list of paragraphs and reset current paragraph for next one
            {
                paragraphs.Add(CurrentParagraph);
                CurrentParagraph = string.Empty;
                newParagraph = true;
            }
            else // we're still in the same paragraph, add the line to current paragraph
            {
                newParagraph += (Environment.NewLine + line);
            }
        }
    }
    // Careful, if your file doesn't end with a newline the last paragraph won't count as one, in that case add it manually here.
}

public static Random rnd = new Random();

// And this returns a random one
public static string GetRandomParagraph(string fileName)
{
     var allParagraphs = GetParagraphs(filename);
     allParagraphs[rnd.Next(0,allParagraphs.length-1)]; // pick one of the paragraphs at random, stop at length-1 as collection indexers are 0 based    
}
```

Note that if you're always reading from the same file this could be much faster by only calling GetParagraphs once and keeping the list of paragraphs in memory.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static string GetRandomLine(string filename)
    {
        var lines = File.ReadAllLines(filename);
        var lineNumber = _rand.Next(0, lines.Length - 1);
        var blankBefore = lineNumber;
        var blankAfter = lineNumber + 1;
        string reply = "";

        while (lines[blankBefore].Length > 0)
        {
            blankBefore--;
        }

        while (lines[blankAfter].Length != 0)
        {
            blankAfter++;
        }

        for ( int i = blankBefore + 1; blankBefore < blankAfter; blankBefore++)
        {
            reply += lines[i];
        }
        return reply;
    }
```

Based on your description, I'm assuming the file begins and ends with a blank line. By setting the exclusive upper bound of the random line to be one less than the length of lines, you avoid the chance of the random line being the last line of the file. If the random line is a blank line, blankBefore will be the index of that line, otherwise, it will be back tracked until it reaches the previous blank. blankAfter starts as the index of the next line after the random line and if that line is not blank, blankAfter is increased until it is the index of the next blank line.

Once you have the index of the blank lines before and after the target paragraph, simply append the lines between them to reply.

If the first and last lines of the file are not blank, you would need to verify that blankBefore and blankAfter remain within the bounds of the array.

Answer (score 0):

I made some modifications to the code provided above by @TheCoderCrab. I turned the method to a string method so it would return a string. I simply added a for loop append all the characters of the paragraph array on to a new string which returns it to the main. Thank you.

```
public static string GetRandomParagraph(string filePath)
    {
        if (File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            string text = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
            string[] paragraphs = text.Split(new string[] { "\n\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
            string [] paragraph = paragraphs[new Random().Next(0, paragraphs.Length)].Split('\n');

            //Added a for loop to build the string out of all the characters in the 'paragraph' array index.
            string pReturn = "";
            for (int a = 0; a < paragraph.Length; a++)
            {
                //Loop through and consecutively append each character of mapped array index to a return string 'pReturn'
                pReturn = pReturn + paragraph[a].ToString();
            }

            return pReturn;

        }
        else
            throw new FileNotFoundException("The file was not found", filePath);
    }
```